# What is it called when a verb takes its "logical" or "usual" object as its grammatical subject?

Tags: english, terminology, grammar

This usually occurs for objects that are used by a person, and in English often feels to me like an Americanism.  Examples:

The sofa *sits* five.

The wine *drinks* very smoothly.

The car *drives* very responsively.

The food *tastes* good.

This sentence *reads* clunkily.

Comment: “The food tastes good” feels like an Americanism to you? I wouldn’t have said it’s equivalent to the other examples at all. The others are clear dispositional middles (well, perhaps not the first one – that’s just a different transitive usage), but _taste good_ isn’t a middle restructuring of any underlying transitive construction.

Comment: That' s a good point. That example didn't sound like an Americanism to me, but I included it because I thought it was part of the same phenomenon. Upon reflection, if it were the same construction then it would have to be "The food tastes well" or "The food tastes deliciously" with an adverb as opposed to an adjective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are called *dispositional middles*. The term stems from languages which have a morphological middle voice besides active and passive, of which dispositional middles are often one of the functions. For English the term is slightly odd because the active morphology is used.

The classical work on this is Suzanne Kemmer (1993), *The Middle Voice*. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_(grammar)#Middle_voice) also has a brief section on it.

Comment: Thanks! Searching for "dispositional middles" leads me to find that they might also be called "personal middles," but perhaps this is a case of non-standardized academic terminology?

Comment: @JasonEliot I believe that's a matter of whether the disposition is attributed to the subject or to sth unexpressed. So e.g. *the book reads pleasantly* vs. *the atmosphere makes for pleasant reading*. The first is 'personal', because it attributes a disposition to the subject; the second 'impersonal', because it attributes a disposition to something not expressed (books, journals, ...). I would both call them dispositional middles. But the terminology is somewhat free because the kind of functions that middle voice encompasses are not discrete anyway; they form a multidimensional continuum.

Comment: That stuff is amazing! Never looked at it at that angle. Thank you!

Comment: The [Middle Alternation](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/003302.html) is the first one in the classic book on English Verb Alternations. It's almost entirely governed by the matrix verb, but there's significant adverbial participation.